# What is this grey arrow next to my armature? What does it do?

Tags: armature

[image]

What exactly is this? I don't remember setting it manually, when I select it with the left mouse button I just select my armature, does it do anything special? How can I remove it without ruining my rig?

Answer (score 3):

These icons next to any folded item in the outliner are a preview of the other data blocks and objects inside or children of that item. You also have the number of items.

If you unfold it, you can see better what it is:

[image: outliner unfolded]

The arrow icon is an animation data. You can delete it if you want, it will not break your rig.